# CSS positioning things differently between browsers

Tags: css, css-position

I have an interactive graphic I made in Adobe Animate (published as HTML5) and am trying to make it more accessible by adding HTML links so that someone who uses the tab key instead of a mouse can tab through the links on the graphic and so the JAWS screenreader can read it properly. I will eventually make the html links pretty much invisible (but the link bounding box will show) by setting their opacity to .01, but I have it set currently to .51 so I can better see the positioning. I'm getting different results between Safari and Firefox on the Mac and it looks different on Windows, too. On Windows in Firefox and Chrome they display pretty much the same, but the positioning is off between Safari on the Mac and both of them. Windows seems to move them over more to the right and down. The parent div has positioning set to relative and each span tag is set to relative too. I'm not sure what to do at this point to get this working consistently across browsers. Here is the link if you can take a look for me. http://www.personal.psu.edu/pzb4/simba/
Any help will be truly appreciated!

Comment: btw, I only got to October on the positioning. everything after that is pretty far off yet.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` for links.
Example for "May":

```
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    top: 226px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: extra-condensed;
    line-height: 90%;
```

## Updated

Else use percents instead of pixels.

```
    position: absolute;
    left: 31%;
    top: 25%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: extra-condensed;
    line-height: 90%;
```

Comment: Still quite a bit off unfortunately. http://www.personal.psu.edu/pzb4/simba/css.png

Comment: @user3499381 See update.

Comment: using percent looks much better. I'll input the rest and let you know. thanks a bunch!

Comment: [_"Don't ever answer an off-topic question, not via chat, comments, or any other way."_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) ... and that goes for poorly formatted one's too, like this question. So before answering, make sure the the question follow what's stated in [ask]

Comment: Looking good now. Will run it by our accessibility folks here and see what they think. Thanks again, imkremen!

Comment: sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: Unfortunately the links do not work after tabbing to them if i hit the Return key. Not sure what to do to fix this. So close to getting it too. It seems as though the css positioning may be breaking the ability to use the Return key to follow the links.

Comment: I figured out how to make the links work. for each span tag I added roll="link" onKeyDown="javascript:go2Link(event, 'http://simba.psu.edu/news/')" and then made a javascript function to send it there.